# How to write to InMemoryRandomAccessStream and then read?

Tags: c#, stream

I want to write an Image to a stream and read it afterwards.
Im on Win 10 UWP.
My code:

```
InMemoryRandomAccessStream imrasIn = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), imrasIn);
DetectedFaces = await _faceClient.DetectAsync(imrasIn.GetInputStreamAt(0).AsStreamForRead());
```

It does not work, DetectAsync gets an empty stream (Error: Image size is too small).
Do I need other classes? `CapturePhotoToStreamAsync` wants an `IRandomAccessStream` and `DetectAsync` wants a `Stream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to rewind the stream before reading (and after writing to it):

```
imrasIn.Seek(0);
```